# Unable to run *.run intallation packages

Tags: chmod

I'm using xubuntu 15.10 amd64, i tried to install .run packages but couldn't. i did blow jobs:

```
sudo chmod +x sample-file.run

sudo ./sample-file.run
```

i tested this command for a few 64 bit packages like "qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run" and "FoxitReader.x64.1.0.1.run".

this is a result of terminal:

```
sepanta@sepantagroup:/media/sepanta/MY PASSPORT/Linux/64$ sudo chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run

[sudo] password for sepanta: 
sepanta@sepantagroup:/media/sepanta/MY PASSPORT/Linux/64$ sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run

sudo: ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run: **command not found**

sepanta@sepantagroup:/media/sepanta/MY PASSPORT/Linux/64$
```

Comment: Often this behaviour  is a result of trying to run things that are on a filesystem that doesn't support Unix-style permission flags and/or is mounted with the `noexec` flag: the appearance of `/media/sepanta/MY PASSPORT` in your path suggests it's an external device - possibly formatted as NTFS or FAT?

Comment: problem solved, problem was that external HDD with ntfs file system. i copied to home folder and files runs.

Comment: @A.M How coincidental that was what I was writing in my answer, heh.  If you'd like, you can accept that answer as the answer, in order to mark this question as answered/resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the permissions on your external drive.  As indicated by your file path, it's a directory in `/media/$USER/MY PASSPORT`.  WD makes My Passport drives, but they create NTFS by default.

NTFS does ***not*** support the `+x` executable bit.  No NTFS supports the capability to execute with just doing a `chmod +x`.  You will need to mount the drive with the `exec` mount option, which permits execution of files.

You may also wish to just copy the `.run` file to your actual home directory and execute it from there:

```
cp '/media/sepanta/MY PASSPORT/Linux/64/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run' ~
cd ~
chmod +x ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run
```